# SQL calculate the day difference between current row and next row based on GroupId

Tags: sql, sql-server

Original table is as below, the table has been ordered by `GroupId` and `Date` in ascending order. I'd like to calculate the day difference between current and next row for the same `GroupId`:

| GroupId | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-20 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 2022-02-27 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 2022-03-02 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2022-02-03 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2022-02-17 00:00:00.000 |

The target output should be like this:

| GroupId | Date | Previous_Date | Day_Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-20 00:00:00.000 | null | null |
| 1 | 2022-02-27 00:00:00.000 | 2022-02-20 00:00:00.000 | 7 |
| 1 | 2022-03-02 00:00:00.000 | 2022-02-27 00:00:00.000 | 3 |
| 2 | 2022-02-03 00:00:00.000 | null | null |
| 2 | 2022-02-17 00:00:00.000 | 2022-02-03 00:00:00.000 | 14 |

I got the script as below, but it's getting the `Previous_Date` from the last row and does the calculation, but I would like to keep the `Previous_Date` and `Day_Difference` as `NULL` for the first row as the target table above.

Can someone please help?

My script is:

```
SELECT  
    GroupId,
    [Date],
    LAG([Date]) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS Previous_Date,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG([Date]) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]), [Date]) AS Day_Difference
FROM 
    TestTable
ORDER BY
    GroupId
```

Comment: What database and version do you have?

Comment: @PaulT. It's sql-server, just updated the tag with it

Comment: You need to use a ```PARTITION BY GroupID``` clause so that way the LAG treats each unique GroupID as a "group". Your script is comparing dates between different GroupID so that's why it's not always NULL when you expect it to be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `PARTITION BY GroupId` in [OVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause. `PARTITION BY` that divides the query result set into partitions.

```
SELECT  
  GroupId,
  [Date],
  lag([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId ORDER BY [Date]) as Previous_Date,
  DATEDIFF(day, lag([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId  ORDER BY [Date]), [Date]) AS Day_Difference
FROM TestTable
order by GroupId
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a7f7f0405227fdc611733315bf44b965)

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense and works for me.

Comment: This query running perfect as i received expected output Thank u.. !!